# Batch file to rename copied file to original folder name and content

Tags: batch-file

Using the below to copy random image files from one folder with 1000+ subfolders into another folder (this works great):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd E:\"New folder"
set t=0
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd "%%i"
    set /A t+=1
    set n[!t!]=0
    for %%f in (*.jpeg *.jpg *.gif *.bmp *.png) do (
       set /A n[!t!]+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )
    set /A "rand=(n[!t!]*%random%)/32768+1"
    copy "!file[%rand%]!" E:\samples\"New folder"
    cd..
)
pause
```

Now, i'd like each copied file in the new folder to be renamed as the subfolder it came from and to list within the name the number of image files and video files in that subfolder.

like so: "SubfolderName (250+10).jpg"

- 250= image files in original subfolder
- 10= video files in original subfolder

can this even be achieved in batch?

Comment: The answer is **yes**, although I'd suggest it foolish to use both spaces and parentheses in filenames if not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Compo i'll be happy to use any other form you can suggest